# Android Studio Commons Math "NoClassDefFoundError"

Tags: java, android

I'd like to use the Apache Commons Math library for computing standard deviation rather than writing my own method, but I haven't been able to get rid of this error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: io.github.hactarce.qtimer, PID: 25294
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lorg/apache/commons/discovery/tools/DiscoverClass;
    at org.apache.commons.math.stat.DescriptiveStatistics.newInstance(DescriptiveStatistics.java:91)
    at ...
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "org.apache.commons.discovery.tools.DiscoverClass" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-24.0.0_9d3ba58e638ed02faa84bf39a48fe2d24bde6b2a-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-me.zhanghai.android.materialprogressbar-library-1.1.6_3f4dfaff6ac84c0f0b41e456c4c7ea77b367a4b0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-internal_impl-24.0.0_92a109cb571bd624e4bea6328895341c772d7c6c-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-commons-math-20040218.045431_cdd6a0543f856d0d318fbe7a891815a73a580ce9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-24.0.0_2a3a8f3ca104420ae4ace8cc58b02d413c7612ea-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-24.0.0_bffc8401f241a00ed2f701ca43e6dffa2f80398d-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-recyclerview-v7-24.0.0_2c37df8ad6003e99ec2537a49be829f52468f887-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-appcompat-v7-24.0.0_73746d492da138f16fa685b4e64eeb56d351948f-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/io.github.hactarce.qtimer/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-animated-v
```

My Gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'Google Apis:Google Apis:23'
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "io.github.hactarce.qtimer"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.0'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:commons:0.8.6.0'
    compile 'commons-math:commons-math:20040218.045431'
}
```

I've seen many other answers about similar errors, but none of them seem to help. Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Wow, that is an **old** version. 2004! Well, it looks like it needs `commons-discovery`, so you need to add that dependency too. To fit what you have, you likely need `commons-discovery:commons-discovery:20040218.194635`. Given that it has the same *(very old)* date, they likely fit together. --- Suggestion: Upgrade to something more current. I mean, Android didn't even exist back then!

Comment: Yikes... maybe I _will_ reimplement them myself. :s

Comment: Why reimplement yourself? Just use a [newer version](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/index.html), e.g. `org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1`. Version 3.6.1 was released on 2016-03-21.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely not be using the jar referenced in your build file.  It is not an officially released version. It is an unreleased snapshot build, pre-dating version 1.0 of Commons Math.  As suggested in the comments, you should upgrade to a released version, preferably 3.6.1.